# How to pass function name by argument to use as a onclick eventlistener?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a chrome extension where I am adding a button to the page and then adding an onclick event to it. Since I want to add more buttons, I wanted to have it dynamic..

```
addAutoModButton('Auto-Moderate', 'moderate');

function addAutoModButton(name, onclickfunction)    {
    ...
    ...
    //creating a button and adding it
    var modbtn = document.createElement("input");
    modbtn.setAttribute('type','button');
    modbtn.setAttribute('value',name);
    title_header.appendChild(modbtn);

    modbtn.addEventListener("click", window["onclickfunction"], false);
    // thats what is not working

}

function moderate() {
    //do some stuff
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: You don't seem to be defining `onclickfunction` anywhere.

Comment: Untested, but you should be able to write `addAutoModButton('Auto-Moderate', moderate);`, and then `modbtn.addEventListener("click", onclickfunction, false);`. Functions are just data in javascript, so you can pass a function as an argument (not the name of the function as a string, the function itself).

Comment: @Oliver: I'd suggest adding that as a answer.

Comment: @cerbrus I'm not good enough at javascript to be confident in answering without testing it :)

Answer (score 2):

- You need to use the parameter you defined.

  ```
  function addAutoModButton(name, onclickfunction)    {
    ...
    modbtn.addEventListener("click", onclickfunction, false);
                                 ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--
  ```
- Pass the function, not the name of it.

  ```
  addAutoModButton('Auto-Moderate', moderate);
                                 ---^^^^^^^^--
  ```

  You need to define the function before passing it as a parameter though.

---

Alternatively, you could keep it as is (limited to global scope though.) By unquoting the property name passed to window.

```
modbtn.addEventListener("click", window[onclickfunction], false);
                                     ---^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---
```

Before it was resolving statically to `window.onclickfunction`, literally.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are first-class object in JS, so you can treat it like any other variable:

```
function someF(){}
function func2(argumentFunction)
{
    document.body.addEventListener('click',argumentFunction,false);//<-- use argument name
}
func2(someF);//<-- function someF will be used as callback
```

The arguments/variables are references to a function object, that means that JS doesn't really care what name a function has, it looks at what the variable *references*, in this case the argument references a function, that was declared elsewhere but passed as an argument. Pure and simple